# Testing stateProvider state if configured in config in angularJS returns null on $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I have a config like this one:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app.home', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/home',
      template: '<div>Foo Bar</div>'
    });
}]);
```

and a unit test using jasmine like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Module: myModule', function() {
  var $rootScope, $state;

  beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_) {
    $state = _$state_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('must have a route state for home', function(){
    console.log($state.get('app.home')); // this returns null
  });
});
```

However I could not get the state in the config to show up on the array returned by `$state.get()`

I also checked and the file containing the config is loaded and it is there.
Can anyone say what I am doing wrong? Basically I just want to test if the states I am expecting are existing in the config of "myModule"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't need this

```
beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
```

as your module lists it as a dependency already.

My guess is, you aren't bringing in the parent `app` state so your `app.home` state will not be created.

Say your `app` state is defined in `myAppModule`, simply change your `module` line to

```
beforeEach(module('myAppModule', 'myModule'));
```

---

If you don't want to include the module with the `app` state, include a config function **before** your module that creates a fake parent state. For this, you **will** need to include `ui.router`.

```
beforeEach(module('ui.router', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('app', { abstract: true });
}, 'myModule'));
```

Alternatively, you could spy on `$stateProvider.state` and use an `expect` to ensure it was called with `app.home`, eg

```
var $stateProvider;

beforeEach(module('ui.router', function(_$stateProvider_) {
    $stateProvider = _$stateProvider_;
    spyOn($stateProvider, 'state');
}, 'myModule'));

it('must have a route state for home', function() {
    expect($stateProvider.state).toHaveBeenCalledWith('app.home', jasmine.any(Object));
});
```

Comment: Yeah, adding a parent state "app" does seem to solve the problem. However adding the other module as a dependency wouldn't work on my end. How could I be able to mock the parent state only on the unit test, if it is possible?