# Unit Testing AngularJS 'config' Written in TypeScript using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, angular-ui-router, config

I'm currently trying to Unit Test the `config` of a new AngularJS component. We are using `ui-router` to handle the routing in our application. We have been able to successfully test it for all our previous components, but the code for all of them was written in plain Javascript. Now that we switched to TypeScript we are having some issues.

This is the TypeScript code where we make the configuration of the module:

```
'use strict';

// @ngInject
class StatetiworkpaperConfig {

    constructor(private $stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider) {
        this.config();
    }

    private config() {
        this.$stateProvider
            .state('oit.stateticolumnar.stateticolumnarworkpaper', {
                url: '/stateticolumnarworkpaper',
                params: { tabToLoad: null, groupTabId: null, jurisdiction: null, showOnlyItemsWithValues: false, showOnlyEditableItems: false},
                template: '<stateticolumnarworkpaper-component active-tab-code="$ctrl.activeTabCode"></stateticolumnarworkpaper-component>',
                component: 'stateticolumnarworkpaperComponent',
                resolve: {
                    onLoad: this.resolves
                }
            });
    }

    //@ngInject
    private resolves($q, $stateParams, ColumnarWorkpaperModel, ChooseTasksModel, localStorageService) {
        // Some not important code
    }
}

angular
    .module('oit.components.batch.batchprocess.stateticolumnar.stateticolumnarworkpaper')
    .config(["$stateProvider", ($stateProvider) => {
        return new StatetiworkpaperConfig($stateProvider);
    }]);
```

This is the Spec file, which is written in Javascript:

```
describe('oit.components.batch.batchprocess.stateticolumnar.stateticolumnarworkpaper', function () {

    beforeEach(module('oit.components.batch.batchprocess.stateticolumnar.stateticolumnarworkpaper'));
    beforeEach(module('oit'));

    var state = 'oit.stateticolumnar.stateticolumnarworkpaper';

    it('has a route', inject(function ($state) {
        var route = $state.get(state);
        expect(route.url).toBe('/stateticolumnarworkpaper');
    }));
});
```

My issue is when executing the line `var route = $state.get(state)`, as the `route` variable is always null. I could verify that the `config()` method is being executed, but I'm simply out of ideas as to why `route` is always null on my test.

Just for reference, this is the configuration of another component, but using Javascript

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('oit.components.binders.binder.dom_tas.taxaccountingsystem.stateworkpapers.stateworkpapersreview')
    .config(stateworkpapersreviewConfig);

function stateworkpapersreviewConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('oit.binder.taxaccountingsystem.stateworkpapersreview', {
            url: '/stateworkpapersreview?reviewType&binderId&year&jurisdiction&chartId&withBalance',
            templateUrl: 'components/binders/binder/dom_tas/taxaccountingsystem/stateworkpapers/stateworkpapersreview/stateworkpapersreview.tpl.html',
            controller: 'StateworkpapersreviewController',
            controllerAs: 'stateworkpapersreviewCtrl',
            resolve: {
                onLoad: resolves
            }
        });

    function resolves($q, $stateParams, StateTiBinderJurisdictionsModel, WorkpaperModel, localStorageService, StateTiFiltersModel) {
        // Some not important code
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is basically the same, but still, I can successfully test this component's `config` in the way I described, but when I try with the one written in TypeScript I get the error I mentioned.

PD: I'm aware of several similar posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316334/testing-stateprovider-state-if-configured-in-config-in-angularjs-returns-null-on) one), but none of them deal with TypeScript, which is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is huge difference between the TS snippet and the JS one.

I’m not sure why you are using a class to elite a function? `.config` suppose to get a function.

You can write the same code as in JS just with `.ts` suffix, it is a valid TS code.

Then you just can import that config function, pass it all the injectables and test it.

Comment: I know I could use the same code, but the same could be said about writing any TypeScript code as just plain JavaScript I think. I would really like to understand why the code behaves differently when testing it. Even when looking at the transpiled code, I can't figure out why it doesn't work as expected when I test it